# Jhipster cannot open main page

Tags: jhipster

I tried Jhipster today and created a new project following the tutorial.
But when I run `mvnw` command and visit `localhost:8080`

I got this:
[image]

But I have already enabled JavaScript in chrome browser.
Why do I still get this message?
Any advise? Thanks in advance.
This is the status of my project, please refer to the pic below:
[image]

Comment: Have you run BOTH mvn and yarn as explained in doc? https://jhipster.github.io/development/

Comment: Hi I run command mvnw only. Status said okay...I don't know what to do next and investigate the issue...

Comment: Read the doc, you must run **both** servers in dev profile: one for java and one for typescript/webpack

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the readme file and then follow the steps given there:

1. `npm istall`
2. `npm install yarn --global`
3. `yarn start`

Answer (score 0):

I use this in the first time run...
Go to app folder and run:

```
yarn
mvnw
```

and some times.. only for livereload Angular, in another command line window.
Go to app folder and run:

```
run yarn start
```

Answer (score 0):

While generating jHipster gateway one needs to install npm packages separately, if not done this kind of blank page will be thrown.

One can go to project gateway directory and simply hit command `npm install` this will take a some time to download all required npm packages into your gateway application. Once done run `npm start` within project directory, it will run the UI application on port 9000 by default, if not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I did the below steps and it is working for me:

1. `yarn install`
2. `yarn start` or `yarn webpack:build:main`